# Import going slow for only 900 records using ef core and filehelpers

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am only importing about  a 600 rows of records from a csv file but its taking a good 5 - 10 mins to complete which seems wrong for a straight forward flat file dataset.

Association,Team,Level,Last Name,First Name,Position ,Birt Year,E-mail,Phone,Gender
Andover,12U Girls,A,Larsen,Shelby,Forward,2009,test@email.com,123456789,F
Andover,12U Girls,A,Lind,Audrey,Forward,2008,test@email.com,111-111-111,F

The above is an example of the data, I am using file helpers for the task https://www.filehelpers.net/ I know what you may say is that what is slow when doing an import but I would say five to ten mins and beyond for 900 records is slow.

I am using ef core 5 and sql  server 2019.

Im inserting into a sql server database btw.

```
public void Run()
{

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<PlayerImportCSVModel>();
    // To Read Use:
    var result = engine.ReadFile(FileName);
    // result is now an array of Customer
    int teamId = 0;
    foreach (var item in result)
    {  //if the player is already in the system we dont want to import them again.
        //check against fristname,surname,year and email it is very unlikely
        //that a person would ever have all three the same.
        var doesPlayerExist = db.DoesPlayerExist(item.FirstName, item.LastName, Convert.ToInt32(item.BirthYear), item.Email);
        if (doesPlayerExist == false)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            player.FirstName = item.FirstName;
            player.Surname = item.LastName;
            player.PlayerLevel = item.Level;
            player.Year = Convert.ToInt32(item.BirthYear);
            player.IsActive = true;
            player.EmailAddress = item.Email;
            player.IsDeleted = false;
            player.CreatedBy = "System Import";
            player.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (item.Gender == "M")
                player.Gender = 1;
            else
                player.Gender = 2;
            var orgExist = refTable.GetAllRefOrginizations().Where(w => w.Name == item.Association).FirstOrDefault();
            if (orgExist == null)
            {
                Ref_Orginzation org = new Ref_Orginzation();
                org.Name = item.Association;
                org.IsActive = true;
                org.IsDeleted = true;
                org.CreatedBy = "System Import";
                org.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                refTable.AddToRefOrginizaiton(org);

            }
            else
            {
                player.OrginizationId = orgExist.Id;
            }
            var teamExist = team.GetAllTeams().Where(w => w.Name == item.Team).FirstOrDefault();
            if (teamExist == null)
            {
                Team teamRecord = new Team();
                teamRecord.Name = item.Team;
                teamRecord.IsActive = true;
                teamRecord.IsDeleted = false;
                teamRecord.CreatedBy = "System Import";
                teamRecord.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                teamId = team.AddTeam(teamRecord);
                player.TeamId = teamId;
            }
            else
            {
                if (teamExist != null)
                    player.TeamId = teamExist.Id;
            }

            db.AddPlayer(player);

        }
    }


}
```

Class Files

```
public class Player
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public int? OrginizationId { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public string? PlayerLevel { get; set; }

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }

    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConditioningWorkout> ConditioningWorkouts { get; set; }
    public ConditioningWorkout? ConditioningWorkout { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BikeWorkOut> BikeWorkOuts { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notes>? Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? PB { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Team

```
public  class Team
{

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
  public Guid? TennantId { get; set; }
  public int? OrginizationId { get; set; }        
  public string? Code { get; set; }
  public string? Name { get; set; }
  public int? CoachId { get; set; }
  public virtual Coach Coach { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Player> Players {  get; set;}
  public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public int? SessionId { get; set; }
  public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
  public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
  public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Orgs

```
public class Ref_Orginzation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OrginzationId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public Person? Person { get; set; }
    public int? PersonGroup { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, you have at least 900 * 3 queries to database. Sure it will be slow.

Comment: Remove the foreach and create a single query for the 3 queries ... to get just the result you want ... the problem is not filehelper but all the queries you make in forEach ...
Or you can parallelize the foreach but you won't gain much.

Comment: Why don't you want to use SSIS to import data from a CSV file? This would allow you to insert data in batches up to 10,000 records in a few seconds.

Comment: I never said didnt want to  I need to match the org tables and teams to the player id @Maxim

Comment: @csharpdude77 Ok, it doesn't matter. I don't see how much data you have in the tables you insert data into, but I don't see the indexes in your code. Because in this is the case, then every time you insert data into table, you have a table scan to check data exist.

Comment: @Maxim thanks for your solution ended up doing what u said upload it to the server and let the server futher process the file I do that in work as well so should done it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I did what was suggested I imported the records into a flat table using bulk insert but I used dapper as its great way to do it what I did was.

```
public void Run()
{
        List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<PlayerFileUploads>();
        // To Read Use:
        var result = engine.ReadFile(FileName);
        // result is now an array of player
       
        
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        {
            sqlConnection.BulkInsert(result);

        }
 }
```

The file was imported in less than 10 seconds that way ill have a cron job on the server to allow it to be further processed. My question is can con jobs detect when new data is placed into a table.

Comment: BulkInsert works with array of Player entity ?